# Block only port from being accessed outside except localhost

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

On Centos 6 machine, how can I block port 8888 from being accessed except by localhost/127.0.0.1 only using iptables? 
Actually, I have another port that I want to listen on 8000 instead of 8888.

This command blocks access to localhost:8888

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 -j DROP
```

I don't want access to 1.2.3.4:8888  but only to localhost:8888

Answer (score 4):

If you mean by 1.2.3.4 any other IP different than localhost, you can use the following (if I understood you well):

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT
```

The first drop all outgoing traffic to TCP/8888 and the second rule accept it when it originates from localhost.